# Python Kivy collide_point() not recognizing when mouse cursor hovers over widget

Tags: python, kivy

In Kivy I've tried to create a button or widget that changes color/text/cursor-type/etc when the mouse cursor hovers over it. Per suggestions online I used the `collide_point()` method. But I'm running into an issue where Kivy thinks the widget is located above and to the right of its drawn location.

I figured the coordinate systems for the mouse position (`Window.mouse_pos`) and the widget are not the same, but every coordinate change I tried (`to_local()`, `to_widget()`, `to_parent()`, `to_window()`) did not fix the issue. I also ran [this code](https://gist.github.com/opqopq/15c707dc4cffc2b6455f) on my computer, but had the same issue. I'm wondering if I'm missing something, and if anyone had any ideas on what I'm doing wrong. I'm using Kivy 2.2.0.

python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class HoverButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HoverButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.check_for_hover)

    def check_for_hover(self, *args):
        mouse_pos = args[1]
        if self.collide_point(*mouse_pos):
            print('cursor inside widget')
            self.text = 'cursor inside'
        else:
            print('cursor outside widget')
            self.text = 'cursor outside'

class Frame(FloatLayout):
    pass

class HoverApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Frame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HoverApp().run()
```

kv language file:

```
#: kivy 2.2.0
<Frame>
    HoverButton:
        pos_hint: {'x': .4, 'y': .4}
        size_hint: (.2, .2)
        text: 'cursor outside'
        font_size: '22sp'
```

Comment: What OS are you using?  I can't reproduce the problem, the code you post works perfectly, at least on Linux (Gnome Wayland) with kivy 2.2.1

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to determine what the issue was. (This may be mostly a Kivy desktop application issue.) The default 'Scale and Density' on my computer display is 150% instead of 100%. It seems `Window.mouse_pos` does not take into account a change in display pixel density when returning the x and y positions of the cursor.

So to get the correct `mouse_pos`, you have to grab the display density from `Metrics.density` and multiply it by the `mouse_pos` x and y (see edited code below).

[Side note: Interestingly I seem to only have this density issue when using `.collide_point(*mouse_pos)`. `.collide_point(*touch.pos)` works fine. I also noticed with 150% density, depending on the situation I have to multiply the `pos` or `points` of the canvas drawings by the density to make them show up at the desired location. If you're making a desktop Kivy application, these are probably good things to know.]

Code that works on different display densities:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.metrics import Metrics # import Metrics to access display density

class HoverButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HoverButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.check_for_hover)

    def check_for_hover(self, *args):
        mouse_pos = args[1]
        new_x = mouse_pos[0] * Metrics.density # multiply mouse_pos by density
        new_y = mouse_pos[1] * Metrics.density
        new_mouse_pos = (new_x, new_y)
        if self.collide_point(*new_mouse_pos):
            print('cursor inside widget')
            self.text = 'cursor inside'
        else:
            print('cursor outside widget')
            self.text = 'cursor outside'

class Frame(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class HoverApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Frame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HoverApp().run()
```